Running into NodeHasDiskPressure using kubeadm with containerd (invalid capacity 0 on image filesystem)
I have a setup with the default configuration of containerd, containerd config default. I have also set SystemCgroup = true since this installation is on arch linux (and their docs mentioned this). Here is the general overview of the steps I follow:
yay -S kubeadm kubelet kubectl

and edit the /etc/modules-load.d/k8s.conf and /etc/sysctl.d/k8s.conf as mentioned in the docs. After initializing the nodes:
sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 --control-plane-endpoint 192.168.68.105:6443 --upload-certs --cri-socket=unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock

And allowing scheduling on control plane, the control plane runs into NodeDiskPressure. This happens even when I add a worker node. I am wondering how to mitigate this issue. So far I have tried the following:

Use cri-docker instead of containerd
Restart kubelet and containerd
Follow same steps on debian

Any pointers will be really helpful.
PS:
Here is the warning message I get after installing cilium networking on the control plane:
Warning  EvictionThresholdMet     2m16s (x17 over 4m57s)  kubelet          Attempting to reclaim ephemeral-storage

Which might be related. There is ephemeral storage available:
Allocatable:
  cpu:                4
  ephemeral-storage:  18861701499
  hugepages-1Gi:      0
  hugepages-2Mi:      0
  memory:             16165964Ki
  pods:               110
...
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource           Requests    Limits
  --------           --------    ------
  cpu                750m (18%)  0 (0%)
  memory             110Mi (0%)  0 (0%)
  ephemeral-storage  0 (0%)      0 (0%)
  hugepages-1Gi      0 (0%)      0 (0%)
  hugepages-2Mi      0 (0%)      0 (0%)

But still the eviction threshold is being met. Here is the kubelet configuration:
{
  "kubeletconfig": {
    "enableServer": true,
    "staticPodPath": "/etc/kubernetes/manifests",
    "podLogsDir": "/var/log/pods",
    "syncFrequency": "1m0s",
    "fileCheckFrequency": "20s",
    "httpCheckFrequency": "20s",
    "address": "0.0.0.0",
    "port": 10250,
    "tlsCertFile": "/var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet.crt",
    "tlsPrivateKeyFile": "/var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet.key",
    "rotateCertificates": true,
    "authentication": {
      "x509": {
        "clientCAFile": "/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt"
      },
      "webhook": {
        "enabled": true,
        "cacheTTL": "2m0s"
      },
      "anonymous": {
        "enabled": false
      }
    },
    "authorization": {
      "mode": "Webhook",
      "webhook": {
        "cacheAuthorizedTTL": "5m0s",
        "cacheUnauthorizedTTL": "30s"
      }
    },
    "registryPullQPS": 5,
    "registryBurst": 10,
    "eventRecordQPS": 50,
    "eventBurst": 100,
    "enableDebuggingHandlers": true,
    "healthzPort": 10248,
    "healthzBindAddress": "127.0.0.1",
    "oomScoreAdj": -999,
    "clusterDomain": "cluster.local",
    "clusterDNS": [
      "10.96.0.10"
    ],
    "streamingConnectionIdleTimeout": "4h0m0s",
    "nodeStatusUpdateFrequency": "10s",
    "nodeStatusReportFrequency": "5m0s",
    "nodeLeaseDurationSeconds": 40,
    "imageMinimumGCAge": "2m0s",
    "imageMaximumGCAge": "0s",
    "imageGCHighThresholdPercent": 85,
    "imageGCLowThresholdPercent": 80,
    "volumeStatsAggPeriod": "1m0s",
    "cgroupsPerQOS": true,
    "cgroupDriver": "systemd",
    "cpuManagerPolicy": "none",
    "cpuManagerReconcilePeriod": "10s",
    "memoryManagerPolicy": "None",
    "topologyManagerPolicy": "none",
    "topologyManagerScope": "container",
    "runtimeRequestTimeout": "2m0s",
    "hairpinMode": "promiscuous-bridge",
    "maxPods": 110,
    "podPidsLimit": -1,
    "resolvConf": "/etc/resolv.conf",
    "cpuCFSQuota": true,
    "cpuCFSQuotaPeriod": "100ms",
    "nodeStatusMaxImages": 50,
    "maxOpenFiles": 1000000,
    "contentType": "application/vnd.kubernetes.protobuf",
    "kubeAPIQPS": 50,
    "kubeAPIBurst": 100,
    "serializeImagePulls": true,
    "evictionHard": {
      "imagefs.available": "15%",
      "imagefs.inodesFree": "5%",
      "memory.available": "100Mi",
      "nodefs.available": "10%",
      "nodefs.inodesFree": "5%"
    },
    "evictionPressureTransitionPeriod": "5m0s",
    "enableControllerAttachDetach": true,
    "makeIPTablesUtilChains": true,
    "iptablesMasqueradeBit": 14,
    "iptablesDropBit": 15,
    "failSwapOn": true,
    "memorySwap": {},
    "containerLogMaxSize": "10Mi",
    "containerLogMaxFiles": 5,
    "containerLogMaxWorkers": 1,
    "containerLogMonitorInterval": "10s",
    "configMapAndSecretChangeDetectionStrategy": "Watch",
    "enforceNodeAllocatable": [
      "pods"
    ],
    "volumePluginDir": "/usr/libexec/kubernetes/kubelet-plugins/volume/exec/",
    "logging": {
      "format": "text",
      "flushFrequency": "5s",
      "verbosity": 0,
      "options": {
        "text": {
          "infoBufferSize": "0"
        },
        "json": {
          "infoBufferSize": "0"
        }
      }
    },
    "enableSystemLogHandler": true,
    "enableSystemLogQuery": false,
    "shutdownGracePeriod": "0s",
    "shutdownGracePeriodCriticalPods": "0s",
    "enableProfilingHandler": true,
    "enableDebugFlagsHandler": true,
    "seccompDefault": false,
    "memoryThrottlingFactor": 0.9,
    "registerNode": true,
    "localStorageCapacityIsolation": true,
    "containerRuntimeEndpoint": "unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock"
  }
}

